# Upload data to Google Cloud Storage with any offset

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to upload data to Google Cloud Storage object with any random offset (not chunk by chunk). Desirable to have unknow size for target object.

Is any way to do it with JSON API ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Storage seeking within files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248333/google-cloud-storage-seeking-within-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. Uploads to a single object must be done chunk by chunk.

However, multiple objects may be composed into a single, final object. In other words, you could upload all of your pieces as separate objects and then call "compose" on them to produce the correct final object. There are some limits to this approach, though. There's a maximum number of original elements that can be composed together (it's 1024). You'll also need to take care of deleting the original pieces once you're done composing, or you'll be storing twice the data.